# How to Declare Composite Serializer in Scala

Tags: scala, cassandra, hector, cassandra-cli, serialization

```
import me.prettyprint.cassandra.serializers._
import me.prettyprint.hector.api._
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory

val se = StringSerializer.get()
val le = LongSerializer.get.asInstanceOf[Serializer[Long]]
val be = BooleanSerializer.get.asInstanceOf[Serializer[Boolean]]
```

but i am not getting how to declare CompositeSerializer
i tried

```
val ce = CompositeSerializer.get
```

and

```
val ce = CompositeSerializer.get.asInstanceOf[Serializer[Composite]]
```

but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

`val ce = new CompositeSerializer()`